# What does trim() actually do in this validation check?

Tags: php, validation, trim

I'm reading a PHP book, what does the below phrase mean?

> To eliminate leading and trailing whitespace, we use the trim() function.

It's being used in the following condition check:

```
if(!empty(trim($_POST['username'])) && !empty(trim($_POST['email'])))
{
}
```

Comment: Does exactly what it says it does _eliminate leading and trailing whitespace_, `trim("  a ") == "a";`

Comment: → http://php.net/trim

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_trim.asp

Comment: It does exactly what it says in the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) `Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string`

Comment: It trims the string of leading and trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

`empty` is checking to make sure the username and email variable is not empty

! signifies NOT

Here is what empty does http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

> A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

`trim`

> removes all whitespace from the beginning and end of the stringStrip
>   whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a
>   string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

So if you have a string 
`" user "` 
`trim(" user ")` 
returns `"user"`

Comment: But why do you require you to do the formatting in conditional check? When, all that we need is to check if the fields or left blank or not.

Comment: Some users will accidentally type a space before or after typing in there username.  This is mainly used to help the user in case of user error.  This isn't something you would generally use trim for, but it's a decent example.

Comment: Still not clear buddy.  What I understand by trim() is that it formats the text removing unnecessary  spaces but our conditional check duty is to see if the fields are left blank or not. I wouldn't have asked this question if it was to display the variable value of $_POST using echo() function. I'm raised this doubt cause it's unnecessary that we do formatting in conditional check.

Comment: That is not what this code does.  It is not checking to make sure the field is not empty.  It making sure that it is not empty after removing all whitespace.   I can't explain it any better than that.  Look at the order of operation here, there is a difference.  If you don't understand the difference try running the code with and without either function with various different inputs and see the difference.  You can question why you would do it this way, that is fine. I personally wouldn't do it this way either.  There are a million and one ways to do user input validation which is what this is

Comment: oh okay let me try to understand by running the code with and without the trim() function.  Thanks alot for your time to explain me in detail :)

Comment: @Naresh Remove all whitespace, then check if there's anything left… in other words, it won't let fields which only contain whitespace pass the check.

Answer (score 1):

The `trim()` function is used to remove blank spaces in a string.
For example:

```
$str = ' abc ';
echo trim($str);
// output will be: abc
```

So, as you can see, it remove spaces from the beginning and the end of the string. You can use `ltrim()` to remove spaces from the left or `rtrim()` to remove spaces from the right.

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 0):

The trim() function removes whitespace and other predefined characters from both sides of a string. Related functions: ltrim() - Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the left side of a string. rtrim() - Removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the right side of a string. 
      Please visit this url:- http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

I hope by visit this link you can learn more about trim function.